# How to create @Trasactional on Private method in Spring Proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions

Here is the code snippet.

```
public class A{

  public void m1(){
    //Do some stuff
    m2();
  }

 @Transactional
 private m2(){
   // Some DB operations
 }
}
```

In the above code, **@Transactional** is not working.

Is there a way where I can create **@Transactional** only on private method (not on public)?

Can someone please help.

Comment: You cannot use this with a proxy based approach in AOP. You will have to use either load or compile time weaving and full blown AspectJ if you want this. Or don't use `@Transactional` but wrap the call to `m2` in a `TransactionTemplate` to do  your own tx management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no purpose of keeping `@Transactional` on private method, because this method eventually being called within the class itself. So proxy will never apply on that method.

> When using proxies, you should apply the `@Transactional` annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the `@Transactional` annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings.

Comment: Usecase is such that I will have to create @Transactional on private method. Can you suggest if there is any approach ?

Comment: @Transactional you can add but it will not make any difference in the code execution, and there is no other way to do it.